# Check my proof of $\int_{X} |fg|\le (\int |f|) \text{esssup}|g| $

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X$ be a measure space and $f, g: X\to \mathbb{R}$ be two measurable functions. Show that
$$
\int_{X} |fg|\mathrm{d}\mu\leq \left(\int_X |f|\mathrm{d}\mu\right) \text{esssup}|g|
$$
where $\text{esssup}|g|:=\inf\{M: |g|\le M \text{ almost everywhere}\}$.

---

My proof is that note that
$$
|g|\leq\text{esssup}|g|
$$
Then
$$
\int_{X} |fg|\mathrm{d}\mu\le \left(\int_X |f|\mathrm{d}\mu\right) \text{esssup}|g|
$$

Does it make sense?

Comment: $g|\le\operatorname{esssup}|g|$ _almost_ everywhere. But it doesn't affect the integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact $|g(x)| \leq esssup|g|$ a.e.  (almost everywhere) not everey where. And if $f$ and $g$ are two real positive measurable function then $\int_Xfd\mu \leq \int_Xgd\mu$ applying this lemma  on the following inequality $|f(x)g(x)| \leq |f(x)|esssup|g|$ a.e. integrating both sides we will get $\int_X|gf|d\mu \leq (\int_X|f|d\mu)esssup|g|$ .